# Hibernate giving aliases inside functions even if it's a number

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, jhipster

Good day, We I have a field with @Formula which is called like this :

```
@Formula("(select isnull((select case when( DATEADD(\"MONTH\", -6 , GETDATE())>  s.activation_date or d.device_first_data_send is not null ) then '1' else '0' end from telematic_device d join sim_card s on s.id = d.sim_card_id where d.id = id),0))")
```

This is JHipster app, so spring & spring paging & hibernate. 
Also we use MSSQL. 
So during paging this request turns into

```
(SELECT inner_query.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_row_nr__ FROM ( select TOP(@P0) telematicd0_.id as id1_12_, telematicd0_.billing_state as billing_2_12_, telematicd0_.consumer_id as consumer9_12_, telematicd0_.device_first_data_send as device_f3_12_, telematicd0_.i_mei as i_mei4_12_, telematicd0_.manufacturer as manufact5_12_, telematicd0_.product_name as product_6_12_, telematicd0_.shippment_date as shippmen7_12_, telematicd0_.sim_card_id as sim_car10_12_, telematicd0_.status as status8_12_, telematicd0_.tenant_id as tenant_11_12_, (select isnull((select case when( DATEADD("MONTH", -6  as page0_, GETDATE())>  s.activation_date or d.device_first_data_send is not null ) then '1' else '0' end from telematic_device d join sim_card s on s.id = d.sim_card_id where d.id = telematicd0_.id),0)) as formula0_ from telematic_device telematicd0_ order by telematicd0_.id asc ) inner_query ) SELECT id1_12_, billing_2_12_, consumer9_12_, device_f3_12_, i_mei4_12_, manufact5_12_, product_6_12_, shippmen7_12_, sim_car10_12_, status8_12_, tenant_11_12_, DATEADD("MONTH", page0_, formula0_ FROM query WHERE __hibernate_row_nr__ >= @P1 AND __hibernate_row_nr__ < @P2
```

However there is a problem : we get this as page0_ inside a function for a number which is obviously a problem and/or a bug in hibernate itself.

```
( DATEADD("MONTH", -6  as page0_, GETDATE())>  s.activation_date
```

So the question would be - did anyone see this before and is there a way to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Assuming you use H2 in unit tests, does it work with H2?

Comment: Yep,  in h2 it works without any issues.  :)